# webView.onPause() does not stop audio of a internal video playing

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a webview that it is showing a video. I want that when the activity onpauses the video stop playing audio and when the activity resumes the video must resume playing audio.

tryed with `webView.onPause()` but does not work. audio is still playing even with the device locked **or with the app closed**.... (lol)

exists a real way to pause audio playback of a video inside a webview?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To me, I have to interject to HTML code to pause the video element in HTML file.

Link util to interject java to HTML:
https://github.com/mttdat/utils/blob/master/utils/src/main/java/mttdat/utils/WebViewUtils.java

**How to use in the activity (Java):**

[image]

**How the HTML looks like:**

[image]

Comment: This is working as expected, we just need to be sure about the player id and the function name. Kudos mate Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using the method `onPause()` of the of `WebView` when is executed the method `onPause()` of your `Activity`

```
@override
public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        webview.onPause();
        }
}
```

it works for API >= 11 (`Honeycomb`)

Comment: I know this post & question is old, but I am facing the same issue and my question to you, is: do you realise that you have proposed the exact same solution that OP did ? Because I also tried and it did not work.